# Should I calculate the sample size in terms of p(1-p) or the given standard deviation?

Tags: statistics

A firm has been hired to conduct a survey. 
Goal: To produce estimates of both average annual income and proportion with PSC in a target population. 
A simple random sample from the population will be used. 
Informed pre-study guesses are that (i) 37% of this population has a PSC, and (ii) the standard deviation of annual income in this population is around $ 22000.

The boss desires a 95% confidence interval $\pm0.05$ for the proportion with PSC and a 95% confidence interval with width no more than $\$5,000$ for the average income in the population.

Using the pre-study guesses, and being mindful of not proposing a more costly study than necessary, what sample size do you recommend?

Should I calculate the sample size in terms of p(1-p) or standard deviation?

n=74 (from standard deviation) and n=358 (from p(1-p))

Comment: You need to satisfy both conditions, so use the larger $n$.

Comment: the larger n is not correct.

Comment: Is this because when dealing with proportions, a conservative estimate needs to assume that $p=\frac{1}{2}$ (which maximises $p(1-p)$)? Did you use $z=\pm 1.96$ for the confidence interval of 95%?

Comment: I used  p = 1/2 so n= 385 and my answer is still wrong.

Comment: my formula is 0.25/(0.05/1.96)^2 = n

Comment: I think the $0.25$ should be $(0.37)(0.63)$ and should be squared, i.e. $(0.37^2)(0.63^2)$. That is the smaller of the two $n$ values, however. From the income CI, you should get $n=(\frac{1.96*22000}{2500})^2\approx298$ since the CI is at most $\pm2500$ (the half-width).

Comment: I think the width for the proportion should be actually no more than 0.05 so 0.05/2  = 0.025, for p = 0.5 I get n = 1438 while for p = 0.37 i get n = 1537 and by using SD i get n = 298.  So clearly the largest n and the one i should select is 1537? But the question suggest not to propose a costly study so i am not sure which n I should use.

Comment: For $p=0.37$, I get $n=(0.37)(0.63)(\frac{1.96}{0.05})^2\lessapprox359$. The question says $\pm0.05$ is the 95% CI for proportion, so this should equate to $1.96$ times the sample standard dev $s$, and it shouldn't be halved. The previous calc for proportions was wrong as the population standard deviation is $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$ not $p(1-p)$. So I think the answer is $359$ (the proportion condition forces the use of the larger $n$). Note: whatever $n$ value is calculated needs to be rounded up.

Comment: but why are we now not considering p = 0.5? that yields a greater n ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29324/discussion-between-marconius-and-tree).

Comment: You just asked this question a few hours ago in another post.